# Accessing std::tr1::smart_ptr in Visual 2012 instead of std::smart_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-studio-2012, smart-pointers

We have a project that uses both visual studio 2010 and visual studio 2012. In the 2010 project we use tr1's implementation of the smart pointer. This code has multiple dependencies and therefore cannot be changed without a lot of hassle. This is then linked to the 2012 solution, in which we tried to use std:smart_ptr.

At compilation time this falls through since the two versions of smart_ptr are not the same which is fair enough, even though I originally thought they would be.

Reading through similar problems on the net one solution is to use boost to add the correct stuff to the tr1 namespace, but we do not want this as an extra dependency other than a total last resort.

Is there any way to get access to tr1's smart pointer in visual studio 2012 as opposed to simply the std:: version so that it compiles without error? I have tried just using std::tr1::shared_ptr in visual studio 2012 and this does not work, is there perhaps a header or something I need to include. We already have the `<memory>` header included and obviously each code base compiles independently of each other. Any help is appreciated

P.S Changing the platform version to 100 instead of 110 isnt possible either. Again there are further dependencies stopping this from happening.

Comment: In general, you can't mix VS2010 and VS2012 code because they do not share a standard library. Even though both have a class named `std::string`, that doesn't mean the implementations are bit-compatible.

Comment: So there is no way for cross compatibility at all then, without using the same platform version or using boost then?

Comment: Well, with COM you can even mix C++ and VB.Net code, but that's probably not the direction you were thinking of. With just C++, `extern "C"` function which do not rely in any way on the standard library could be safe. But even a hidden reliance (say on `malloc/free`) is troublesome.

Comment: Fair enough. Probably just need to use boost then, which isnt a big deal but was hoping to avoid it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Keep in mind that Boost definitely relies on the Standard Library. You might be able to solve this by providing a replacement for `operator new` and `operator delete` on both sides that will interwork, at least in case of `smart_ptr` as it's fairly simple.

Comment: Yeh we could do that but again its a lot of extra work. Unfortunately the code bases are used for other projects and changing any one of them means we will no doubt have to change them all. Time for a rethink most likely.